# Can off-diagonal elements in a covariance matrix ever be greater than the diagonal elements?

Tags: covariance-matrix

Can off-diagonal elements in a variance-covariance matrix ever be greater than the diagonal elements?

Comment: Are you asking whether the off-diagonal elements can be greater than the *maximum* of the diagonal elements? Or whether an off-diagonal element can be greater than either one of the two *corresponding* diagonal elements?

Comment: If possible, could you please answer these two sperate cases: [1] off-diagonal elements can ever be greater than the maximum of the diagonal elements? [2] Is a diagonal element the largest among the row elements of the same row? Thanks, Stephan!

Comment: Contemplate $\pmatrix{9&2\\2&1}.$

Comment: @Art1 I answered to the two questions in your comment, please include them in the original question if this is what you really want.

Comment: Covariances and variances often have quite different units of measurement, so the question hardly arises.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. Consider the example with two variables $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Suppose $$Cov(X_1,X_2) > max\{Var(X_1),Var(X_2)\}$$

Then it must be that $$Corr(X_1,X_2) > max\biggl\{ \sqrt{\frac{Var(X_1)}{Var(X_2)}}, \sqrt{\frac{Var(X_2)}{Var(X_1)}}\biggr\}$$

Suppose that $Var(X_1) > Var(X_2)$, then

$$Corr(X_1,X_2) > \sqrt{\frac{Var(X_1)}{Var(X_2)}}$$

But this is impossible since

$$1 \geq Corr(X_1,X_2) > \sqrt{\frac{Var(X_1)}{Var(X_2)}} > 1$$

The same would hold if you suppose that $Var(X_1) < Var(X_2)$.

2. No. By the same reasoning you can have

$$Cov(X_1,X_2) > Var(X_1)$$

since it is possible to have

$$1 \geq Corr(X_1,X_2) > \sqrt{\frac{Var(X_1)}{Var(X_2)}} > 0$$

if $Var(X_1) < Var(X_2)$.